# Android GraphView gets Laggy and Sometimes too fast

Tags: android, android-studio, plot, graph, bluetooth

So what i am doing is:

1)Receive characters(integers in the for of chars) from a BLE model(dont know it? its not important anyways)

2)convert those chars into double

3)plot it on y axis, with x axis being time,

The ble sends a value once every 100 milli seconds.
And the phone catches and changes that value, so no problem there.

1)To receive data:

```
String data = new String(byteArray);
```

2)convert those chars(string) into double:

```
Double d=Double.parseDouble(data);
```

3)plot it on y axis, with x axis being time:

```
Runnable mTimer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                graphLastXValue += 1d;
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(graphLastXValue,d), true, 40);
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
            }
        };mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer, 1000);
```

THE PROBLEM:
Once the x value(graphLastXValue) goes beyond some 700, the graph lags!!

FEW QUESTIONS:

1)what are those postDelayed doing?, what would be their best values in order to plot data that is obtained at one value per 100 milli seconds?

2)Any easier(this isnt hard though), ways to plot data?

Comment: did you found any solution ?